# Проблема в решении задачи "Valid string" c Code Wars (6 kyu)

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, уже который день бьюсь с [задачей на code wars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52f3bb2095d6bfeac2002196), никак не могу написать полноценное решение, перекрывающее все нюансы.

Суть задания:
Проверьте, может ли строка (`word`) быть полностью сформирована последовательным соединением слов словаря (массив `dictionary`). Шаблон решения:

```
var validWord = function (dictionary, word) {
  
});
```

Примеры:

```
dictionary: ["code", "wars"]

s1:         "codewars" =>  true  -> match 'code', 'wars'
s2:         "codewar"  =>  false -> match 'code', unmatched 'war'
```

Comment: Можете подробнее указать, при каких входных данных какие должны быть выходные

Comment: Задача https://www.codewars.com/kata/52f3bb2095d6bfeac2002196

Comment: Ты просишь готовое решение этой каты, правильно понимаю?

Comment: var validWord = function(dictionary, word). Функция принимает два аргумента, массив со словами и само слово. Выходное значение имеет тип boolean(true или false)

Comment: Да, сам я решить его, видимо, не в состоянии.

Comment: Ну там же есть миллион решений

Comment: @AlexeyTen, посмотреть их без потери чести можно только после сабмита своего решения :)

Comment: Ну да, попросить решение на SO гораздо честнее 

Comment: @AlexeyTen, честь не в буквальном смысле, а та что на codewars, хонор (если верно помню, она там типа очков опыта - для повышения ранга). Безумие конечно лютое, но тем не менее, это всяко лучше чем кабанчиков в ММОРПГ резать (или на танке давить, или что там сейчас модно).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наверное, самый простой способ — дать регулярным выражениям всё сделать за вас. Объединяем все слова в массиве через символ 'или' (`|`), заключаем весь комплекс в скобки и разрешаем любое количество повторений этого комплекса от начала до конца строки.

```js
function(dictionary, word) {
  return new RegExp(`^(?:${dictionary.join('|')})+$`).test(word);
};
```

Comment: Невероятно, спасибо большое.